# An inversion ???

Tags: subjunctives, reflexive-pronouns

I don't get this quote below in grammar. Could you analysis this sentence for me？

"Waive" is a verb, so it can't be the subject. This quote seems in inverted order. Is it an inversion?

But just "MFAT should waive immunity if there are allegations of serious crimes" is enough to elucidate the point clearly, what "request it" does here?

---

> According to MFAT, foreign diplomats in New Zealand have immunity from
>   any criminal processes, including investigations and prosecutions.
>   However, the New Zealand government makes it clear foreign diplomatic
>   staff must abide by the law and “**waive immunity should MFAT request it
>   if there are allegations of serious crimes**”.

source: [US diplomat ejected from New Zealand after police fail to get immunity waived](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/19/us-diplomat-ejected-from-new-zealand-after-police-fail-to-get-immunity-waived)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two VPs headed by *abide* and *waive* are conjoined by *and*; they have the same subject and modal auxiliary:

```
                                   ( abide by the law
... foreign diplomatic staff must -( and
                                   ( waive immunity should MFAT request it
```

*Should MFAT request it* is a conditional with inversion: it's equivalent to "if MFAT should request it".

This use of conjunct VPs often implies that the second VP provides an interpretation of the first, so you might paraphrase

> The New Zealand government makes it clear that in cases where serious crimes are alleged, foreign diplomatic staff must obey the law by waiving immunity if MFAT asks for that.

Comment: You haven't read the rest of the article. "The ministry appealed to the US embassy to waive the man’s immunity on the same day, but the US government refused," indicates that they don't make the decision. They had to ask the US to waive.

Comment: Your explanation is good though :)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Syntactically, the only possible subject of *waive* is *foreign diplomatic staff*. It doesn't make any difference that practically or legally speaking the waiving might be done at some higher level.

Comment: @DavidPostill Obviously the embassy's between a rock and a hard place--under NZ law they **must** waive immunity, but under US law they **must** follow the instructions of their own government.

Answer (score 5):

*However, the New Zealand government makes it clear foreign diplomatic
staff must [abide by the law] and [“waive immunity should MFAT request it
if there are allegations of serious crimes”].*

The subject of "waive" is "foreign diplomatic staff".

The clause consists of a coordination of two VPs (bracketed) functioning as complement of the modal auxiliary verb "must".

The second coordinate is a conditional construction where "if there are allegations of serious crimes" is a conditional clause and "waive immunity should MFAT request it" is what is necessary to fulfil the condition. The latter contains the further emedded conditional clause "should MFAT request it" which has inverted order.